# How convert PDF to ACROFORM type?

Tags: forms, pdf, pdftk, fdf

I use pdftk for filling forms.
and now when I enter

```
F:\GoogleDisk\projects\comparepdfs>pdftk new/file.pdf 
fill_form new/b2bf7150aa9de8b2ef8edd20a5677f7f.fdf output new/temp_b2bf7150aa9de8b2
ef8edd20a5677f7f.pdf
```

returned

```
Warning: input PDF is not an acroform, so its fields were not filled.
```

How fix it or convert PDF to acroform?

Comment: How was the form to be filled created? Does it have fillable fields at all?

Answer (score 1):

I decided it.

Combine files in Acrobat - and it create new pdf.

New pdf is good.